# Form title bar multicolour

Tags: forms, delphi, customization

I have a question about form appearance.
I would like to create an application that looks likes some MacOS app (for example Bear or even the App Store. These application are characterized by the left part (a sort of drawer) that is of on1y one colour.

I would like to have my forms created with Delphi in the same way.
I've looked at the internet and I've tried, as suggested, to use VCL style, but there are some problem due to Windows dpi setting on the various PC that run the application. So I wonder if there is a way to reach this task coding.

In the image below you can see how a normal window appear in a PC with Windows 10

[image]

The example is greeting with a simple form in which I put a panel painted of blue.
As you can see the titlebar of the windows is white and it can be painted with a color using the VCL styles (but in this case all the titlebar should be of that color.

What I would like to have is something like the following image (created in Photoshop )in which I've traced a red line only in order to highlight the titlebar:

[image]

I've tried with intercepting WM_NCPAIN or other similar solution but I can't find a way to reach my task.
Can someone help me with this problem?
Many thanks in advance

Comment: I'd recommend to either remove the title bar altogether (using `bsNone`) or leave it as it is - the blue bar is client stuff, the title bar is non-client area.

Comment: Search for "delphi custom title bar". What part/color you want is not important, you'll assume full NC painting.

Answer (score 1):

*In Windows Vista and later, the appearance of the non-client areas of application windows (the title bar, icon, window border, and caption buttons) is controlled by the DWM (Desktop Window Manager). Using the DWM APIs, you can change the way the DWM renders a window's frame.* (quote from [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/dwm/customframe)).

There is an article [Setting up a custom title bar on Vista/Windows 7](https://delphihaven.wordpress.com/2010/04/19/setting-up-a-custom-titlebar/) that explains how to do this using Delphi. The article also applies to Windows 8.x and Windows 10. The author has written a number of articles on the subject; you can find an overview [here](https://delphihaven.wordpress.com/category/glass/).